# Estimate distribution from mean and prediction intervals

Tags: regression, machine-learning, boosting, quantile-regression

I'm using an ML-model (gradient boosting) to predict mean, upper and lower quantiles of a target variable which is gamma distributed.

I want to construct distributions for the predictions and figured that given that I have upper and lower quantiles (can be set to whatever quantile I want) I can maybe estimate some distribution parameters.

Since the target variable is gamma distributed, I'm assuming I will want to construct gamma distributions from the single predictions also. The error seems to follow a normal distribution.

How do I translate values from quantiles and the mean to the parameters of a gamma distribution? Or perhaps to the variance?

EDIT: Put in another way, how can I estimate shape and scale of a gamma distribution given I have the mean and two quantile values?

Comment: What error do you have in mind in *The error seems to follow a normal distribution*?

Comment: The residuals from y_true - y_pred, where y_true is the real observed data for the target and y_pred is predictions from the ML-model.